# Oracle Sequence increment by 0.5

Tags: oracle, sequence, auto-increment

i am new to oracle 
but i want the sequence that increment by 0.5 how it possible?

[image]

kindly help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 3):

Will , You can't create a sequeance that will increment by 0.5 but you can use a trick

```
create sequence sq start with 1 increment by 1;

select 0.5 * sq.nextval from dual connect by level < 11

| 0.5*SQ.NEXTVAL |
------------------
|            0.5 |
|              1 |
|            1.5 |
|              2 |
|            2.5 |
|              3 |
|            3.5 |
|              4 |
|            4.5 |
|              5 |
```